# how to execute sql command from command line using NO script file?

Tags: sql, command-line, firebird

is there any way to execute `update contact set email_address='foo@bar.com';` using `isql` (firebird) on linux?

I don't want to use `-i` switch to specify sql script file. And I cannot use interactive mode as I will run the sql command from php script.

Comment: What does `echo "update contact set email_address='foo@bar.com';" | isql` do? I haven't used firebird but that should work with any sensible tool.

Comment: @mu: do you want to create an answer from the above? It works nicely :-) thank you. The whole lot looks like `echo "update contact set email_address='foo@bar.com';" |/opt/firebird/bin/isql -user SYSDBA -pass password /var/lib/firebird/data/radek_db.gdb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sensible SQL shells do The Right Thing when fed commands on the standard input so you should be able to just `echo` your SQL into `isql`:

```
echo "update contact set email_address='foo@bar.com';" | /path/to/isql --your-favorite-switches
```